# Remove class from one list without removing it from others

Tags: python, list, class

I have a piece of code which is doing a different thing to what I feel it should. This is a module I built to test this problem in a larger piece of code:

```
class plant:
    def __init__ (self, param):
        self.param = param
plants = []
for i in range(10):
    plants.append(plant(10))
plant1 = plants[0]
plants1 = plants
print(len(plants))
for i in plants:
    print("Item removed")
    plants.remove(i)
print(plant1)
print(len(plants))
print(len(plants1))
```

This produces the output as

```
10

Item removed

Item removed

Item removed

Item removed

Item removed

<__main__.plant object at 0x02780F30>

<__main__.plant object at 0x02780F30>

5
5
```

Why does it remove the items from plants1 as well but not from plant1? And how do I stop it doing that?

Comment: you need to copy the list `plants1 = plants[:]`

Comment: or use `.copy()` which works for dicts as well.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham definitely similar answers but though it's a question about duplicates it's not necessarily a duplicate question!

Comment: Thank you. What does my code there do which makes it behave that way?

Comment: @Sacasco, the answer to how to change it is in the first comment I made and the reason why is in the link.

Comment: @dsclose: it certainly is a dupe; the other post *answers* this one.

Comment: SO member Ned Batchelder has a nice articles (with diagrams) that explains what's going on: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Therelevant part of your code is here:

```
plant1 = plants[0]
plants1 = plants
```

`plant1` now refers to tthe object at the first index of `plants` and this will still point to that same object even if it's removed from `plants`. You still only have one object, rather than two duplicates.

Similarly, `plants` and `plants1` refer to the same list. You have not duplicated your list by assigning one to another. Thus anything you do to `plants1` you are also tacitly doing to `plants`.

Really, you need to look at this [question on duplicating a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).